# Routing in asp .net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I created a default ASP .NET MVC 4 Internet Application in Visual Studio.

In the _Layout.cshtml, for the case of three action links of *Home*, *About* and *Contact*, the *home* link goes to `http://localhost`, but the other two go to the respective action and controller ((`http://localhost/home/about`) and (`http://localhost/home/contact`)).

Why such difference occurs. Just because index action of home controller is default, does compiler think that *html.action* link for *home* will go to `http://localhost` and not `http://localhost/home/index`. ?

Here is the code in _Layout.cshtml

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
```

The code in routeconfig.cs is

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Default",
   url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

**Edit**

I understand that `http://localhost` will redirect to *index* action of *home* controller but why is the html.actionlink giving the link as `http://localhost` and not `http://localhost/home/index`. ?

**Edit 2**

This *defaults* in routeconfig would imply that in the event that the url is simply localhost, only then the default action and controller is to be taken. When routeconfig would be executed, the url for parsing is *localhost*. My question is why isn't it *localhost/home/index*, since in actionlink we're specifying the name of controller and action? Is the compiler so intelligent that the url for *localhost/home/index* is simply converted to *localhost*?

I know that localhost is redirected to index action of home controller, but **my question is that** in the home page as specified by the _Layout.cshtml, why is the url for home link different than that of about and contacts?

Comment: bcoz it is default route

Comment: @Nilesh : but in the code in _layout.cshtml, where did we ever indicate such a thing. There's no difference in the above 3 links, and we we not indicating in any way that the link for home is default

Comment: @Nilesh: when routeconfig would be executed the url for parsing is localhost. My question is why isn't it localhost/home/index, since in actionlink we're specifying the name of controller and action?

Comment: @user3547820 when suitable route found, in your case it route _Default_, mvc checks which params come in and if some parameters is absent then using parameters from default. no redirect

Comment: @Grundy please see edits and comments to other answers

Comment: As per my experience and knowledge, generally in default page we are not displayed full URL.  Like Yahoo.com, Stackoverflow.com, flipkart.com. We are generally shows only domain name in any site (for home page). This is not very easy for everyone to remember the full URL. (Like domainname.com\pagename). That's why we are giving the menu functionality to user, because if they want to see any other page in our application then they can go on that page easily.

May be to achieve this functionality/thing in default URL, you are not getting the full URL in Html.ActionLink for default route.

Comment: @user3547820 yep, url generator so intelligent that generate shortest url by params, and don't use some parameters if they are the same as default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its probably because of this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new {
        controller = "Home",
        action = "Index", 
        id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

What you pass for `defaults`...

Comment: This defaults would imply that in the event that the url is simply localhost, only then the default action and controller is to be taken. When routeconfig would be executed the url for parsing is localhost. My question is why isn't it localhost/home/index, since in actionlink we're specifying the name of controller and action? Is the compiler so intelligent that the url for localhost/home/index is simply converted to localhost?

Comment: To a degree it depends on which rule your route engine hits first. However, in your case, it evaluates the "Default" rule, and executes the Index action of the Home controller, because that is what is specified as value to `defaults` parameter of the `MapRoute` call.

Comment: route engine will act on the url which is passed to it. It's the duty of html.actionlink to make sure what url is passed (which is localhost). Now even if i put in the url http://localhost/home/index, the url is simply not changed to localhost. This implies that route engine has nothing to do with the url passed to it except parsing it. So why is action link passing only localhost?

Comment: when you call Html.AcionLink the url is generated using the routeconfig it passes from RouteConfig so it is default it will simply return the root url which is localhost on dev server and on live it can be different

Comment: "Default" is the last rule executed. The engine understands that it has no `{controller}` and `{action}` sections defined. But that route has some `defaults` defined. Hence the engine will go with that. The reverse is also true. When you do a `@Html.ActionLink("Index","Home")` it is clever enough to output only `/`

Answer (score 0):

you are setting this route default, so it will be your application start url, like index.html in html pages.

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Default",
   url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Here you are telling that its a default route so in this case it will not display action and controller name in the url.